# how to solve algebraic fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is

$$ 1/2n = 1 - 1/n$$
what i did was i first added the 1/n and tried to simplyfy it

$$ 1/2n + 1/n = 1$$
$$  1n/2n(n) + 2n(1)/2n(n) = 2n(n)/2n(n) $$ 
I don't know if i did this right, i remember teacher telling me to use factored form.
 and this is what i got 
$$ 3n/2n(n) = 2n^2/2n(n)$$ than i multiplied 2n(n) from both sides getting
$$ 0 = 2n^2 - 3n $$
I won't be able to get zeroes from this or did i do the whole thing wrong

Comment: The goal is to solve for $n$?  If so then you might find it easier to multiply both sides of your original equation by $2n$.

Comment: The wise strategy is to multiply both sides by $n$, since you know that $n$ can’t be zero. Gives you $\frac12=n-1$. Maybe @lulu’s suggestion is quicker.

Comment: ohh okay thanks...but was my way wrong or just the way i did was complicated??

Comment: Inefficient, and may have introduced false solutions.

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow your calculation because the formatting is unclear.  However the final equation that you get seems correct...as you know from the original form that $n≠0$ you can divide through by $n$ and get $n=\frac 32$ which is correct.

Comment: so for n i got 3/2 and you know when you have to plug it in the original equation, i got 1/3 = -1/3?  does that mean that equation is empty brackets or has no solution

Comment: If you take $n=\frac 32$ in the original equation you get $\frac 13$ on the left and $1-\frac 23$ on the right.  As these are equal, the solution holds.

Comment: Ohh okay i forgot about the negative thanks again

Comment: @MATHASKER Regarding to your deleted question I commented: Im not sure if I have understood the exercise. I would say that the cost of each rental tape weekly increases by factor $1.25=\frac{3.0}{2.4}$. The reciprocal is $0.8=\frac{2.4}{3.0}$ Then the new weekly total number of rentals is $0.8\cdot 3000=2400$ I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{2n}{2n}-\frac{2}{2n}$$
$$\frac{2n-2-1}{2n}=0$$
$$2n-3=0$$
$$n=\frac{3}{2}$$